# Views aren't respecting the ?destination=xxx in the URL

Tags: 7, views, redirection

Using Drupal 7/Views 3, I created an admin page for a custom content type. When I click on a node edit link on a row, I'm directed to node/33/edit?destination=admin-mycontent ,where I can edit the node.

If I perform an operation like adding a field, the "destination=" in the URL is ignored, and when I save my changes, I'm directed to the node view, instead of back to my admin page.

If I cancel instead of save, I'm directed back to my view.

How can I have the expected redirect when I save the node?

Answer (score 1):

It's not views, is the Drupal core. When creating/saving a node, you are automatically redirected to that node. You could create a module that hooks into node saving form and redirect you to the url destination path.

you should also check the [rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules. It seems that could do the job for you.